# Multiple categories with one posts in sql query in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, wordpress

I Made two tables

1. **posts**
2. **categories**

In **posts** table I created category column, here I store multiple category_id like this **1,2,3**.

The problem is if category column has single category_id like **1** or **2** or **3**, I can easily query the data like this:

```
SELECT title FROM posts WHERE category = $category_id
```

However, I am unsure as to how to query the comma-delimited data.  Is there a way to do this, or should I change the table structure ?

Comment: Add another table. Call it `posts_categories` with post_id and category_id.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Add a junction table which has  2 foreign keys refering to both Posts table and Categories table. like @aynber said. the 3th table will only refere foreign keys to the primary tables.

Comment: Why the MS SQL Server tag?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here you can have:
Categoryid: 1
Postid: 1,2,3

Result = Categoryid: 1 --> Postid 1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

You could either create a junction table (probably with an [EAV design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)) or keep your unique table and use [FIND_IN_SET](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php), as such :

```
SELECT title FROM posts WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, category) > 0
```